# MEW offline transactions broadcasting

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, offline

When I create a signed transaction on my offline computer and then broadcast it on my online computer. What hinders a node to broadcast it again after my transaction is included in a block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found it out in the meantime. The nonce prevents double spends. Google Ethereum tx nonce to get more information.